# PDF does not work in Adobe Reader DC but all other Readers

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

I am unable to get my pdf to work online with Adobe Reader DC.

http://www.okeechobeecountytaxcollector.com/Documents/FeeCalculatorRev0909.pdf

None of the buttons or functionality is working. (Like when you click motorvehicles, or Mobile homes or any of those buttons across the top a drop down of choices is supposed to appear) But if I open in any other reader it works fine. Does anyone know how I may be able to edit the document to work properly in Adobe Reader DC as well? Is there any settings in the document or anything that you have to change for things to work in DC?

I have tried changing the settings in the security section to Acrobat X and later but that did not fix it as well.

Comment: Are other PDF's working with Adobe?  I am wondering if Adobe itself is the problem rather than the file.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I did not have any problem using the form, as far as I can tell. It may be the Adobe installation. Remove and reinstall Reader to see if that fixes it.

Comment: You have adobe DC? I works on all adobe readers except adobe DC

Comment: Most the form is working except the top row. The buttons motor vehicles, mobile homes, vessels heavy trucks, Lease, and trailers. When you click them something should appear. In DC it is not working. But in the middle of the page if you click florida title, manufacturer mco, and out of state title those dropdowns appear.

Comment: This works fine in adobe acrobat X and XI but we are trying to move up to DC and this pdf is breaking that we need so I am trying to figure out how I can make it work in DC.

Comment: @CharlieRB were you able to see anything clicking those buttons?

Comment: Actually, I am using Acrobat X. The more I am clicking I am getting `JavaScript : Warnings` asking for form numbers. For instance, when I clicked the birth month, it gave a warning window asking for a number. Also when I clicked `Motor Vehicle` it asked for number of months. After that, I get a combo box with choices.

Comment: thats normal but when you switch to DC it does not give you those warnings. Those warnings you are getting is it working properly. When you switch to DC nothing happens when you click them

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't much help then.

Comment: hahaha download DC and see my problems!!! haha

Comment: @CheesusCrust yes other pdfs are working but none have them have javascript like this one does.